# display xslt formatted data in excel

Tags: excel, xslt

I have written a test code which reads data from a XML file (Data.xml) and uses a XSLT file (XSLTFile1.xslt) to filter out desired records and format it accordingly. This output is saved in another output.xml file. Upto this point it works fine. Now what I want is to display this output in excel sheet as it is. Till now I am able to dump this data as a whole into excel sheet but I want to specify some constraints:
•   I want that if I have output  in red color the excel cell color should also be red.
•   I want to specify a cell location like G12 or (12:7) where I want to show that data.

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("Data.xml");

System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(
"Customers.htm", System.IO.FileMode.Create);

//Create an XmlTextWriter for the FileStream.
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xtw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(
fs, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);

//Transform the XML using the stylesheet.
XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(dataSet);
System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform xslTran = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform();
xslTran.Load("XSLTFile1.xslt");
xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, xtw);

//Open the HTML file in Excel.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
oExcel.Visible = true;
oExcel.UserControl = true;
Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
object oOpt = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
oBooks.Open("customers.htm", oOpt, oOpt, oOpt,
oOpt, oOpt, oOpt, oOpt, oOpt, oOpt, oOpt, oOpt,
oOpt, oOpt, oOpt);
```

The output file data:

Comment: Any thoughts anyone? I am till now able to display data after saving formatted output in html. Still i am unable to specify cell location in sheet where i want to display that data.

Comment: I am not sure you can use XSLT to make an EXCEL sheet from XML. I know you can use JAVA to do that. You might wanna add the tag "java" and maybe someone there knows more.